# Global sections of the structure sheaf of a projective scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective scheme (not necessarily reduced). Under what assumption is it true that $h^0(\mathcal{O}_X)=1$? In general can we bound $h^0(\mathcal{O}_X)$ by the dimension of the projective space in which it is emebedded? (Here $h^0(\mathcal{O}_X):=\dim H^0(\mathcal{O}_X)$)

Comment: No. This has much less to do with dimension than it does with the number of components.

Comment: @Matt: How is it related to the number of components?

Comment: For example, for a smooth and projective scheme over a field, it equals the number of components. Just try out $X=\prod_1^n Spec(k)$. Note this fits inside a small dimensional projective space.

Comment: @Matt: Does a similar result hold for projective but not reduced?